# Load different directive depend on screen size at AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 1 different component layout loaded by directive at bigger and smaller screen.

Is it possible to do that at AngularJS?

Have read the doc from [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options) and [here](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.1/layout/children) but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get screen size in Angular with:

```
$scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;
```

---

Based on this line, just `ng-if` or `ng-show` your div:

```
<div directive1 ng-if="windowWidth < 768">
    Directive1 on small screens
</div>

<div directive2 ng-if="windowWidth >= 768">
    Directive2 on large screens
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I just did that and it works now.. Will accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$window.innerWidth` property inside your directive and manipulate your template accordingly.